# How to construct an optimal ranking function?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-science

I have a set of numerical features `(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5)` as follows for each user in my dataset.

```
       f1   f2  f3  f4  f5
user1  0.1  1.1  0 1.7  1
user2  1.1  0.3  1 1.3  3
user3  0.8  0.3  0 1.1  2
user4  1.5  1.2  1 0.8  3
user5  1.6  1.3  3 0.3  0
```

My target output is a prioritised user list. i.e. as shown in the example below.

```
       f1   f2  f3  f4  f5  target_priority
user1  0.1  1.1  0 1.7  1       2
user2  1.1  0.3  1 1.3  3       1
user3  0.8  0.3  0 1.1  2       5
user4  1.5  1.2  1 0.8  3       3
user5  1.6  1.3  3 0.3  0       4
```

I want to use these features in a way that reflect the priority of the user.

Currently, I am multifying all the features of each user to get a score and rank the users based on the score (example shown below).

```
       f1   f2  f3  f4  f5  multipled_score predicted_priority
user1  0.1  1.1  0 1.7  1        0              5
user2  1.1  0.3  1 1.3  3        1.287          2
user3  0.8  0.3  1 1.1  2        0.528          4
user4  1.5  1.2  1 0.8  3        4.32           1
user5  1.6  1.3  1 0.3  1        0.624          3
```

However, merely multiplying the features and rank based on the `multiplied score` did not perform well. I think the features should be `upweight` or `downweight` based on their contribution in correctly predicting the priority.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is a way (in machine learning/data science/statistics) to get a optimal ranking function using the scores of my features to get a ranked list closed to the real ranking.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to tackle this problem is by using a machine learning algorithm that tries to learn the *underlying function* in order to predict the most likely score of a new user based on its features.

Note however, that the model will not perform well unless the amount of samples isn't high enough. Five samples are obviously not enough, this is just a sketch to give you an idea on how you could approach this using machine learning.

I will be using [`RandomForestRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) as an example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
```

Lets start by defining the features and target that will be fed to the model.

```
X_ = df.drop(['target_priority'], axis=1).values
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X_)
y = df.target_priority
```

Now lets fit the model:

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
rf.fit(X,y)
```

Here I have not split the data in train and test sets, but you should be doing that in order to have an idea of how well your model performs. Here given that there is a single sample for each existing target, I've trained the model with all samples, and will be creating a test set by adding some noise to the training data:

```
noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.2, size=X.shape)
X_test = X + noise
```

And now you can obtain predictions on the test set using the trained model:

```
y_pred = rf.predict(X_test).round()
# array([2., 2., 4., 3., 4.])
```

A you can see, even with the small amount of samples used to train the model, the model has been able to predict with an average error of only `0.4`:

```
np.abs(y - y_pred).mean()
# 0.4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. I have the following two questions that I thought would be great to ask from you. 1) Currently my features are in different ranges (e.g., `f1` -> [0,3], `f2` -> [0,5], etc.). Do you recommned to convert them all to a unit range `[0,1]` before I fit to random forest? 2) Is it possible to get the importance/contribution of each feature in predicting the results? Thank you once again :)

Comment: Well, for random forest specifically it is not necessary to normalize, but I did so because for some other algorithms as SVM it will be necessary. And yes, you can have an idea of how much each feature contributs on the prediction you can use [`feature_importance`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.feature_importances_). You're welcome :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I upvoted and accepted the answer as it solved my problem :) Btw I got my real dataset today and it is not how I expected. It has some users with `no priority label`.  That is because such users are not important to our company (more like general users). In such cases, is it good to give them a `special symbol` or `a priority level that is much much lower (e.g., 100000000000000000 priority)`? Do you have any suggestions for a label for such users? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Ah yes sorry @emi, will give you a reply in a bit

Comment: hi, just wondering if you had time to looki into my problem mentioned above. It would be really great to know you suggestions on them. Thanks a lot once again :)